# How to manage disk 'quota' in Ubuntu 21.04 as have installed it as '/' in one SSD and '/home' in another SSD?

Tags: networking, server, disk-management, quota

Snap of nano `/etc/fstab`:

[image: Snap of nano /etc/fstab]

Snap of `sudo lsblk`:

[image: Snap of sudo lsblk]

As I have trouble in have successfully installed quota in machine but not working for `/home`.

Please share the solution for the issue. Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: its 'Quotas' not 'quota' as above question.

Comment: If there is a mistake or new info for the question do not make a comment fix the mistake or add the info to the question.

Comment: Have you read `man -k quota`? Don't post pictures of text. Copy and Paste, use AskUbuntu's formatting tools. Disk quotas are per filesystem, have you set up quotas for `/home`? Don't call your pictures "snaps", even  if it's colloquial  - `snap` is a Ubuntu packaging method, and confusion could happen

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code